# Special characters issue on Linux while reading data from sybase db using java

Tags: java, linux

Initially we are storing data in database using ASCII format.
While reading the same data I am using `getASCIIStream()` method of `ResultSet` to avoid character set conversion problem. This method is giving proper data in windows environment but when I deploy the war file in Linux environment then it is displaying ? mark instead of special characters.
eg: Data stored in Database : `§©µ`

Retrieved value in Windows environment : `§©µ`

Retrieved value in Linux environment : `���`

Below is the snap shot of code:

**Mapper.java**

```
InputStream inputStream = resultSet.getAsciiStream("supplier_destination_operator");
```

Below is the code snap shot which I used to convert above input stream to string.

```
BufferedReader reader;
StringBuilder target = new StringBuilder();
int asciiVal;
if(inputStream != null) {
    try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    while((asciiVal = reader.read()) != -1){
    char ch = (char)asciiVal;
    target.append(ch);
    } catch(e){}
    return target.toString();
}
```

Comment: Obviously your code has a bug. Why don't you show your code.

Comment: Edit your post and put the whole code relevant code there, not a single useless line of code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the default character set used by your Windows and Linux installations.Just print `Charset.defaultCharset()` and see whether the values are the same.

And when you are creating a reader, pass a Charset explicitly to make it truly environment agnostic.